# su silently fails with bash in /etc/passwd

Tags: bash, debian, shell, su

Whenever I attempt to su to root by using `su` while logged in as a regular user on my Debian machine it silently fails, dumping me back into my original user and shell. While searching for this problem I came across solutions that explained that this behaviour is supposed to happen if the user I attempting to login to has an invalid shell in `/etc/passwd`, which doesn't seem to be the case, the first line on the file is: `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`.

The only way I can su to root is with:

```
su -s /bin/sh
```

Since it looks like the problem is with the `bash` installation itself, I tried reinstalling `bash` with `apt-get install --reinstall bash` while logged in as root, but the error still persists. How can I make it possible to login to root using bash with just `su`?

I just noticed that if during the timespan between hitting enter after entering root password and being dumped back into my original user I try hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, `su` works and I am logged in as root in bash.

If I'm logged in as `root` using a shell, and run `/bin/bash` from there, it returns me a Segmentation fault error.

I tried running `/bin/bash -x`.  It seems to run forever printing `/opt/spark//bin:/opt/spark//bin:/opt/spark//bin`.  When forced to stop with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, it runs `bash` with `root` user as if nothing happened. `strace /bin/bash` seems to be showing that the command tries to open `/root/.bashrc` over and over again until it segfaults.

Comment: Have you checked (with `cat -et` for example) that there are no trailing non-printing characters (such as a stray carriage return) on the password entry?

Comment: The first two lines of output of `cat /etc/passwd -et` are `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash$
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin$`

Comment: Is `/bin/bash` in `/etc/shells`?

Comment: @AndyDalton Yes, it is. What I just noticed is that if during the timespan between hitting enter after entering root password and being dumped back into my original user I try hitting `ctrl+c`, `su` works and I am logged in as root in bash.

Comment: I assume you can run `/bin/bash` successfully?

Comment: @JeffSchaller As root? If I'm logged in as root using shell, and run `/bin/bash`, it returns me a Segmentation fault error.

Comment: That's probably the problem; `su` runs your shell, which segfaults.

Comment: @JeffSchaller How would I proceed to fix this? It seems weird that when I hit `ctrl+c` before `su` returns me to original user I can login as root.

Comment: Have you looked at the system logs for the possible origin of the segfault, or attempted to run the `su` command through `strace`?

Comment: You may try `/bin/bash -x` to see if there's something in the login profiles that is segfaulting; otherwise, strace could help if bash itself is segfaulting.

Comment: @JeffSchaller `/bin/bash -x` seems to run forever printing `/opt/spark//bin:/opt/spark//bin:/opt/spark//bin`, when forced to stop with `ctrl+c`, it runs bash with root user as if nothing happened. `strace /bin/bash` seems to be showing that the command tries to open `/root/.bashrc` over and over again until it segfaults.

Comment: The contents of /root/.bashrc would be illuminating, I think. I suspect a typo in trying to add to $PATH, but that's just a guess.  [EDIT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/429306/edit) the contents of /root/.bashrc into your question (so that the formatting can keep it readable)

Comment: @JeffSchaller You are right! The only three non commented lines on `/root/.bashrc` were
`export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark/
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
source ~/.bashrc`. When I commented those 3 lines, `su` works perfectly, I suspect some other student was setting up Spark in this machine, but I can't see why this three lines would be making bash not work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem stems from an infinite loop in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark/ 
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin 
source ~/.bashrc
```

When placed in your ~/.bashrc file, you'll successfully su to the user and run your shell, but you'll never get a prompt.

The minimal fix would be to comment out the `source` line.